# Disable/Deny all protocols except ws:// in Node Media Server (Nodejs)

Tags: javascript, node.js, media

I would like to deny access to anyone trying to read my stream from http or rtmp protocols.

I am learning on the fly, so I'm no dev, kinda rookie actually.. so if you could explain to me how to do this in simple terms.. I'd really much appreciate it !

Here the code I'm using right now and that allows every protocols to be played...

```
const { NodeMediaServer } = require('node-media-server');

const config = {
logType: 3,

rtmp: {
port: 1935,
chunk_size: 60000,
gop_cache: true,
ping: 60,
ping_timeout: 30
},
http: {
port: 8080,
allow_origin: '*',
},
};

var nms = new NodeMediaServer(config)
nms.run();
```

The best would be an if statement, but I've been searching/testing but I didn't succeed.

Thank you for your help and time !

Comment: I'm not familiar with NodeMediaServer and can't answer your question about how to block access through certain protocols, but the WebSocket protocol is built atop HTTP-- you definitely shouldn't try and block HTTP if you need to use WebSockets!

Comment: @Connor Well, it's not that I want to block http, I just want http and rtmp to return 403, but ws to return 200.. but can't figure out how.... :/ or at least, redirect http and rtmp requests to ws..

Comment: I see. Perhaps you could intercept connections and terminate them with the `preConnect` event? I can't find terrific documentation for the package you're using, so I'm not sure what arguments get passed to it: `nms.on('preConnect', (id, args) => { /* ? */ });`

Comment: @Connor Thanks for your answer, I'll try to dig it out and see where it goes ! :D